# I'm unable to resolve AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'to_tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow

[image: The error occurring in my code is here]

[image: I tried opening the ops.py file of TensorFlow but I was not able to resolve that error]

I have to use the function in transformers so that I  have to convert the ragged tensors to normal tensors using the to_tensor() method, which pads the tensors and sets the dimensions to [None, tokenizer.model_max_length] so you can feed different size tensors into your model based on the batch size.

The entire code is :

```
train_ds = qa_dataset['train']
test_ds = qa_dataset['test']




from transformers import TFDistilBertForQuestionAnswering
model = TFDistilBertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("model/tensorflow", return_dict=False)
 

# 
# #### Train and test datasets
# 
# **Note:**
# * In the TensorFlow implementation, you will have to set the data format type to tensors, which may create ragged tensors (tensors of different lengths). 
# * You will have to ` method, which pads the tensors and sets the dimensions to `[None, tokenizer.model_max_length]` so you can feed different size tensors into your model based on the batch size.  

# In[58]:


import tensorflow as tf

columns_to_return = ['input_ids','attention_mask', 'start_positions', 'end_positions']

train_ds.set_format(type='tf', columns=columns_to_return)

train_features = {x: train_ds[x].to_tensor(default_value=0, shape=[None, tokenizer.model_max_length]) for x in ['input_ids', 'attention_mask']}
train_labels = {"start_positions": tf.reshape(train_ds['start_positions'], shape=[-1,1]),
                'end_positions': tf.reshape(train_ds['end_positions'], shape=[-1,1])}


train_tfdataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_features, train_labels)).batch(8)


# #



EPOCHS = 3
loss_fn1 = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy( from_logits=True)
loss_fn2 = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy( from_logits=True)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5)

losses = []
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print("Starting epoch: %d"% epoch )
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_tfdataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(x_batch_train)
            loss_start = loss_fn1(y_batch_train['start_positions'], answer_start_scores)
            loss_end = loss_fn2(y_batch_train['end_positions'], answer_end_scores)
            loss = 0.5 * (loss_start + loss_end)
        losses.append(loss)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
        opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

        if step % 20 == 0:
            print("Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"% (step, 
                                                                   float(loss_start)))




from matplotlib.pyplot import plot

plot(losses)




question, text = 'What is your name?','My name is rahul. The rahul is south of the bedroom.'
input_dict = tokenizer(text, question, return_tensors='tf')
outputs = model(input_dict)
start_logits = outputs[0]
end_logits = outputs[1]

all_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_dict["input_ids"].numpy()[0])
answer = ' '.join(all_tokens[tf.math.argmax(start_logits, 1)[0] : tf.math.argmax(end_logits, 1)[0]+1])
print(question, answer.capitalize())
```

This part of the code works perfectly in the Coursera notebook as I saw in the QA model by using transformers

Comment: The tensor on which you are trying to call `to_tensor()` is already a tensor and **not** a ragged tensor. That is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @Safeerkhan Don't attach codes and errors as images, as they are not helpful for the community to search and find the same error.

Comment: please check the question now, the code has to use to_tensor() as I am using this code from QA model of cousera and  i have provided the code now.

Comment: the tensorflow version i use is 2.9.1 I think i need to add the to_tensor() attribute to the ops.py file of tenserflow